# State space equations

Tags: homework, control-systems

I am stuck on this exercise. I don't know how to deal with this squared y in the denominator. What am I supposed to do to obtain state space equations?

ex.1
Simplified dynamic model of the steel ball kept in the magnetic field has the following form:
$$my'' = mg - C{u^2 \over y^2}.$$

u – voltage of the magnet, y – vertical ball position, g – gravitational constant, m – mass, c – constant. We
consider normalization m = g = c = 1.

1. Write down state space model equations.
2. What is the operational point for y = 1?
3. Write down the linear model equations around that point.
4. Write down the respective transfer function.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two principles here:

1. When dealing with a differential equation, you define intermediate state variables so everything is in terms of first derivatives.
2. This system is nonlinear, so the state-space equations won't be in terms of matrices.

Applying these principles, we define a state vector:
$$
\mathbf x = [x_1, x_2]^T,
$$
where:
$$
x_1 = y \\
x_2 = \dot y
$$
Note that:
$$
\dot x_1 = x_2
$$
Substituting these into your original equation yields:
$$
\dot x_1 = x_2 = f_1(x_2) \\
\dot x_2 = g - \frac{C}{m} \frac{u^2}{x_1^2} = f_2(x_1, u)
$$
which is of the form:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = 
\mathbf f(\mathbf x, u, t)
$$
Since the model coefficients (i.e. $C, g, m$) don't depend on time, we can drop the $t$:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = 
\mathbf f(\mathbf x, u)
$$
Now that you have a put the ODE in explicit form, [you can take derivatives to find the operating point](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/101108047/module7/Lecture%2016.pdf).

The basic idea is to approximate $\mathbf f(\mathbf x, u)$ with a first-order Taylor approximation about some operating point $(\mathbf x_0, u_0)$:
$$
\mathbf f(\mathbf x, u) \approx \mathbf f(\mathbf x_0, u_0) + (\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0) \frac{\partial \mathbf f}{\partial \mathbf x}\Bigg|_{(\mathbf x_0, u_0)} + (u - u_0) \frac{\partial \mathbf f}{\partial u} \Bigg|_{(\mathbf x_0, u_0)}
$$

EDIT:

From the referenced lecture slides, note that:
$$
\mathbf f(\mathbf x, u) = \mathbf f(\mathbf x_0 + \Delta \mathbf x,  u_0 + \Delta u) = \dot{\mathbf{x}}|_{(\mathbf x_0, u_0)} + \dot{\Delta \mathbf{x}},
$$
where $\Delta \mathbf x = \mathbf x - \mathbf x_0$, $\Delta u = u - u_0$, and
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}|_{(\mathbf x_0, u_0)} = f(\mathbf x_0, u_0).
$$
This leads to a linear, time-invariant system in terms of the state variable $\Delta \mathbf x$:
$$
\dot{\Delta \mathbf{x}} = \mathrm A \Delta \mathbf x + \mathrm B \Delta u,
$$
where:
$$
\mathrm A = \frac{\partial \mathbf f}{\partial \mathbf x}\Bigg|_{(\mathbf x_0, u_0)} \\
\mathrm B = \frac{\partial \mathbf f}{\partial u}\Bigg|_{(\mathbf x_0, u_0)}
$$
The solution for this coupled set of equations yields the displacements $\Delta \mathbf x$ from the operating point $(\mathbf x_0, u_0)$.  This is true for any operating point $(\mathbf x_0, u_0)$, regardless of whether or not $\mathbf f(\mathbf x_0, u_0) = 0$.  Also note that this system is LTI mathematically, not physically. In reality, the matrices $\mathrm A$ and $\mathrm B$ can also change with time.

Note that a good [control algorithm based on a linearized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_parameter-varying_control#Gain_scheduling) model will have to update the operating point at a fast enough rate that the nonlinearities don't cause any problems.

Comment: i would call them *Two "**principles**"*.

Comment: It might be useful to note that an operating point has to satisfy $f(x_0,u_0)=0$.

Comment: @fibonatic you can cheat it into an LTI system by solving for the perturbations $\Delta \mathbf x$ for any operating point

Comment: @CarlosDanger If $\dot{x}_0=f(x_0,u_0)\neq0$ then $A$ and $B$ might be time varying matrices, so in general you would have a linear time varying system.

Comment: @fibonatic The linearized system is LTI mathematically, not physically

Comment: @fibonatic I will clarify the answer to make this more explicit